# openssh server: rejected send message

Tags: root, openssh

When I tried to restart the `ssh` server on my ubuntu box, I got

```
me@me-one:~$ service ssh restart
restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.63" (uid=1000 pid=3354 comm="restart ssh ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I realized that I hadn't `sudo`-ed

```
me@me-one:~$ sudo service ssh restart
ssh start/running, process 3386
```

Why didn't the first attempt throw an error like `Permission denied` or something similar. Am I overriding the error when running as `root` and implicitly ignoring the warning/error? Or is it just [bad programming](http://www.nsa.gov/public_info/_files/cryptologic_quarterly/Error_Messages.pdf) by the `openssh` developers?

Comment: Reported the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1059452

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One person's "bad programming" may be another person's "it's working as intended".

It's true that you need root priveleges to restart, start, stop etc and you are getting this message because you don't have those privileges.  But I agree that it would be nice if the message you got when you tried to do so without root privileges was more helpful.

You may want to check if bugs already exist in launchpad about this (presumably under *upstart*) and if not, report it.  It's the sort of thing, though, where I'd be fairly sure you wouldn't be the first person to notice it since it's so common.  Either way, bug research can be rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i now, to start or stop a service you must have Super User prievilages. You must prepend sudo before the command.

To start,

`sudo service ssh start`

To stop,

`sudo service ssh stop`

To restart

`sudo service ssh restart`

To check status,

`sudo service ssh status`

Note:

- sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser.